# Using Nginx to emulate a redis server

Tags: sockets, nginx, redis

My existing application is using a true redis cluster and communicates with the cluster using the StackExchange Redis client.

I’m looking to build a caching layer that emulates some of the redis commands to set and get data. The caching layer I would like to implement would use http protocol for the endpoints.

I would like to use Nginx to handle the persistent connections. I’ve been reading over the stream and socket declarations Nginx has and would have the existing application connect to Nginx and have Nginx forward the messages to the caching endpoints.

Can Nginx behave as a middleware that will keep the connection to the application open while communicating to the caching endpoints in a stateless manner?

Comment: You may find the answers discussed here interesting but it's not clear whether persistent connection is end-to-end, i.e from client-Nginx-application (caching endpoints).  https://serverfault.com/questions/690239/does-nginx-keep-the-connection-open-when-it-does-load-balancing

Comment: I believe this is possible by using the `Nginx stream` module to establish a stream-based connection between the application and Nginx, and then use the `proxy_pass` directive to pass requests from Nginx to the caching endpoints.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve at all, your question is not clear add some examples...